# Why are tags that have zero questions tagged visible when searching?

Tags: support, tags, tag-search

I was just exploring tags and reading their tag-wikis.

I went [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) and typed "infinite" in the search box. Several tags showed up and the last tag that was shown was [infinite-recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infinite-recursion). There was no questions tagged with it.

- How did such a tag come into existence?
- Why aren't any questions tagged with it?
- Why isn't it possible to see/edit its tag wiki?

Comment: It was about to be deleted but got stuck in a loop?

Comment: @rene , Recursion,not a loop ;)

Comment: Yeah, they can't agree on how they are stuck...

Comment: Possibly related (from MSE): [Empty tags (with no questions) are not deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190917/empty-tags-with-no-questions-are-not-deleted)

Comment: It also could be timing - the tag might have just had it's last question removed and will be deleted soon?

Comment: Another possibility is a locked question.  I can't find the post, but IIRC locked posts do not show up in a tag search, so maybe there is still a question out there.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Doesn't prevent the script from running, it's just that if a deleted question that still has the tag gets undeleted, the tag magically reappears.

Comment: @animuson thanks.  I was not very confident in that last thought, but thought I had seen something.  I will remove that idea so as not to confuse anyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How did such a tag come into existence?**

It looks like "infinite-recursion" was suggested as an [infinite-loop synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/infinite-loop/synonyms) tag last June.

**Why aren't any questions tagged with it?**

It could have been a tag previously, and the questions were manually retagged (and the tag subsequently deleted) prior to it being suggested as a synonym. Or it may have never existed as a separate tag, and the "creator" simply thought it'd be a useful synonym.

Suggested synonyms that are currently in use have a number next to them in the `Synonym` column of the [Tag Synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all) page, like *"x 300"* to show that 300 questions are currently tagged.

So far, the synonym has never been used (the "renames" column on the [Tag Synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all) page  shows 0). However, the [vote score hasn't reached +4 or -2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms), so it's still "pending".

**Why isn't it possible to see/edit its tag wiki?**

You can see Tag Info pages for tags that are also pending synonyms, and you can see Tag Info pages for synonyms that are no longer pending (in this case, the Tag Info link leads to the "parent" tag).

Since no question is currently tagged with "infinite-recursion", but it's still just a pending suggestion, it doesn't have its own (or link to an existing) Tag Info page yet.

[image]